# socket comunication - compare C# with Node.js

Tags: c#, matlab, sockets

I'm trying to send TCP message from .Net application to running Matlab script.

Working example of socket client I tested with Matlab server is in Node.js:

```
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect({port: 8000},
    function() { //'connect' listener
  console.log('connected to server!');
  var data = 'Message/';
  client.write(data);
});
```

WireShark sniff for Node.js:
[image]

My C# code (rewritten for naked Socket) is:

```
IPAddress newIpAddress = new IPAddress(16777343);
IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(newIpAddress, port);

Socket s =
    new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
s.Connect(ipe);
int byteCount = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(message);
byte[] sendData = new byte[byteCount];
sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

s.Send(sendData, byteCount, 0);
s.Disconnect(true);
```

WireShark sniff for C# (packages from 6 - 9 are diffrent in Seq and Ack):
[image]

These two solutions tested for Hercules.exe give the same results.

Why c# solution isn't recived by Matlab server?

Comment: try adding a `stream.Flush();` and/or an explicit `client.Close();` before it is disposed? frankly, I'm not sure there's much benefit in `TcpClient` here... looks like naked sockets would be fine

Comment: where to add `stream.Flush();`? After `stream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);`?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant (untested)

Comment: Unfortunately adding `stream.Flush();` did not help. Also tried naked sockets. Matlab is still not receiving data.